# pandas increment under specific condition of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','b','b','b','d'],'B':[0,0,1,2,3,0]})
```

how to get result like in column B?
The idea is when column A row is equal with column A previous row, add 1, else back to 0

I've tried:

```
df['B']=0  
df['B']=np.where(df['A'].eq(df['A'].shift()),df['B'].shift()+1,0)
```

however, the result that i got is [0,0,1,1,1,0] instead
do i missed some steps or non logical operation here?
any hint will be very helpful
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
m = df['A'] != df['A'].shift()
df['B'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount()
```

---

```
   A  B
0  a  0
1  b  0
2  b  1
3  b  2
4  b  3
5  d  0
```

Comment: thank you very much, this one works, if its okay maybe can add explanation on how this approach solves the problem

Comment: @m3wIsw3m Sure! Give me sometime.